# X12 Implementing 270, 271 eligibility verification request

Tags: c#, x12

We are using .net framework 4.0 for our application.

I will give a brief idea of what I am trying to do here. My application needs to submit requests to most of the US States for medicaid eligibilty.

The user fills out a eligibility request form 270 with a verification state field. Based on the verification state field we decide which state to send it to. We submit a request 270 to states by doing a Web HTTP POST or ftp. This depends on the state.  We also have their username, pwds for the respective states. We need these while making the HTTP Request.Each state has its own URL to be submitted to.

Question: What would be a good place to store all these URL's. App.config might get too clumsy. or database?

How would I do a webservice or WCF for this specific application. This is going to be my first Web service or WCF(if I need one here).

Thank u

Comment: I would use a translator with communications built in.  You are reinventing the wheel here.  The most efficient way would be to purchase a tool that can integrate with your systems out of the box with a short learning curve.  What about 997s?  HTTP post - is that with AS2 semantics?  Wrapping EDI in a SOAP envelope?  These are all challenges that have been solved.  You may have a bigger set of challenges than WCF can handle.

Comment: You completely reworded your question.  Are you SURE the communication protocol does not follow the AS2 semantics?  It's rare to send EDI data via standard HTTP.  AS2 provides encryption and signing capabilities.  I'm just trying to help you avoid wasting time building a web service that might not be what the state's want.

Comment: @Andrew: Hi Thanks for looking at my question. I haven't heard them telling me to follow any sematics. We do mostly 270, 271's. All I am told to do is make sure u send/receive 270/271 to/from the state automatically. I guess here I can answer my own question atleast for now!!. Have all the urls, ftp links in a DB. Load it on start/initialize. If I were to do a web servie, then it should build the 5010 format of the EDI. Somewhere down, convert this EDIto a xml just to facilitate sending/receiving based on the state. I haven't done anything like this before. This is what I was told to do :)

Comment: So you are not only doing HTTP, but also FTP (which would need to be handled as a separate service).  It always makes my head hurt when people get forced to write code to challenges that have already been solved.  Companies too cheap to buy software usually spend over twice that writing it themselves.  Building 5010 EDI (translating) and sending are mutually exclusive.  A web service wouldn't build the document, just deliver it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think a database would be best.  Partly because it will probably grow very quickly.  With CAQH CORE http://www.caqh.org/pdf/CLEAN5010/270-v5010.pdf being mandated by the Administration Simplification Act, you might be able to have one web service that does most of them, but Medicaid varies by state, and usually has a budget low enough that you can't count on them being up to date with the standards.  So, you may want the database to tell you two things: which URL to send it to, and which web service to send it through.  That number will probably grow as the project progresses.